# PYQT5 setstylesheet() causing malloc() unsorted double linked list corruption, double free or corruption, and other errors randomly

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, malloc

I'm encountering a weird problem. I have been trying to find the solution for days, and I sincerely ask for your help kind strangers.

**My Code**

I'm using pynput to detect users' keyboard input through a listener. When an instruction is received, the following function runs.

```
1.def reset(self):
2.    try:
3.        for i in range(2):
4.            for j in range(10):
5.                
6.                self.bar[i][j].setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);font: 15pt Arial;}")      #This is a QLable
7.                self.bar[i][j].setText("Preparing...")
8.                self.status[i][j].setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: rgb(133, 133, 133);font: 15pt Arial;}")      #This is a QLable
9.                self.status[i][j].setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("img/status_preparing30.png"))
10.                
11.   except:
12.       print("Error occurred while trying to change CSS.")
13.   sleep(0.1)
```

**My Error**

Most of the time the code works, however, from time to time, 5 different errors will occur randomly and crash the program:

1. malloc() unsorted double linked list corrupted
2. corrupted size vs. prev_size
3. double free detected in tcache 2 python
4. double free or corruption (!prev)
5. Could not parse stylesheet of object QLabel

**My Troubleshooting**

- The error occurs entirely randomly, it can occur when I call the function for the first time, or after many many times. The message I get is random from the above list as well.
- I removed lines 6 and 8, no error occurred.
- I then tried to keep lines 6 and 8, but remove the words in the string inside of the parameter, leaving both an empty string "", no error occurred.

The above error messages mostly relate to memory allocation, according to my search, yet I don't think I have messed with the memory in any way. Therefore I'm so confused. Please help me if you have a slight idea of what's going on. Thank you very much!

Comment: pynput works on a separate thread, and no access to UI elements is allowed from external threads, as widgets are *not* thread-safe. If you want to do that, you must use a QThread with a custom signal, run the pynput listener in that thread (by overriding the `run()` function), emit the signal whenever required, and connect that signal to the function that actually interacts with the UI.

Comment: Note: please don't use line numbers in code, as they make copy/paste difficult and annoying. If you need to point out specific lines in the code, use code comments and eventually reference them in the description.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’ll try it out and get rid of the numbers next time.